# How to enter greek alpha under Xorg?

Tags: linux, localization, keyboard, x11, xorg

I want to enter greek alpha letter under Xorg.  In system xcompose (/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose) there is line:

```
<dead_greek> <a> : "α" U03B1  # GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
```

How to enter it with US keyboard? My locale is `en_US.UTF-8`. What is this key `<dead_greek>`?

Comment: `xmodmap -pke` might give you some hints about nearby keys...

Comment: There is no output from: `xmodmap -pke  |grep -i greek`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just looked up `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` and there is no `dead_greek` character. There are only `dead_acute`, `dead_iota`, and the like to combine with alpha.
There is no plain greek alpha in this file.

If you use gnome, look at this answer [How can I map a character to a key combination?](https://askubuntu.com/a/2326) over at http://askubuntu.com. In your [case](http://graphemica.com/%CE%B1) this would be

<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-u</kbd><kbd>03b1</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

If you have no <kbd>dead_greek</kbd> key in your xmodmap output, you can add one yourself. Search for a key you want to use for that purpose, right windows key or right super key for example. Then you can replace the definition of this key with dead_greek

```
keycode 133 = dead_greek NoSymbol SuperR
```

Comment: File is stock, unmodified from x11-libs/libX11-1.5.0 package.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky Then it might be a distribution thing. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky I just looked and my package's version is 1.4.99.1, so it might be a bit older than yours.

Answer (score 0):

you could put this somewhere that runs after your keyboard is set up in X:

```
xmodmap -pke | awk '/keycode[ \t]+65[ =]/ { $5="dead_greek"; print $0; }' | xmodmap -
```

for my keyboard that maps shift-space to dead_greek.

Takes a bit of getting-used-to.